# Diodes and CMOS 4060 (14-stage counter)

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis

Take a look at this popular circuit for a fridge alarm based around the 4060 binary counter (http://free-electroniccircuit.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/refrigerator-alarm-schematic.html):

[image: Schematic]

One thing I notice is that the diodes connected to pins 3 and 6 are "reversed".  I think I understand why this is the case: that when these pins go high, after a time interval specific to the output pin (and adjusted by the RC arrangement at pins 9 and 10), the current is blocked from flowing through the diodes and instead flows through the transistor base pin causing the buzzer to sound.  My assumption is that when pins 3 and 6 are not high that current freely flows through R4 and the diodes and into the "output" pins 3 and 6.

My question is this: is it "healthy" to pass current though IC pins that are specifically output pins?  Is this a common arrangement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conection of those diodes is called [wired AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection), i.e. the output (= common node after the diodes) is high only when both inputs are high.

The current flowing through the outputs is Ub / R4 = 3V / 100kOhm = 0.03 mA which is well below the max. output current this IC can sink.

So: yes, it's common. It is not unhealthy.

(What you might have in mind is that currents caused by voltages above the supply voltage of the IC and even more by voltages below GND at any input or output must be avoided. This is, however, not the case here)

Comment: Yes, exactly. My worry was that reversing the normal operation of the IC by pushing current through the output pins would damage it in some way.  But, your comments are reassuring and I also now understand that the pulse from "both" pins (thus the AND) must be greater then or equal to the supply.  Many thanks, you've cleared that up nicely.

Comment: @user50500 output pins both source and sink current, their usage here is not out of line with proper operation. When high the O?P pin source very little current because the diode is reversed biased.  When low the O/P sinks current, which is limited by R4.  There is no "pushing" the O/P it self is "pulling".